# postgreSQL Вывод N строку

Tags: postgresql

Есть таблица, выводит естественно 6 строк. Как именно вывести 2 строку например.

```
Select distinct latitude, longitude from russion limit 6
Вывод:
1  ааввав
2  авававава Хочу сделать вывод только этой строки
3  ававававав
4  авававааавав
5  авава
6  ававав
```

Comment: o_O `ORDER BY id LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1`. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT PS. Наличие ORDER BY с правильным выражением сортировки - обязательно. PPS. Офигительные значения у longitude...

Comment: СПАСИБО БОЛЬШОЕ!!!